# value_counts not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and i want to find the number of occurences of a each value. When i use this command

`test = df['name'].value_counts()`

i get correct results but when i try this

`df['occ'] = df['name'].value_counts()`

i get only NaN on the 'occ' column.

My dataframe has 3 columns the first two contain irrelevant values and the third contains the values that i want to count. The dataframe does not have any empty cells.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a [join operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

```
>>> df
  name
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    C
5    A
>>> ts = df['name'].value_counts()
>>> ts.name = 'occ'
>>> df.join(ts, on='name')
  name  occ
0    A    3
1    B    1
2    C    2
3    A    3
4    C    2
5    A    3
```

and you get the occurrences of each name in front of it.